# Just curious as to why the revival badge was not awarded for this question

Tags: bug, badges

The following is the condition stated to receive the revival badge:

> Answer more than 30 days after a question was asked as first answer scoring 2 or more

I believe the condition was met for my post for the following question

[Which is the missing number?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/87668/18418)

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There actually was an older, now-deleted answer with a score of +2.
I would assume this disqualifies your answer for the Revival badge. 
Sorry about that!

Comment: And there I was planning for a Necromancer tag. Oh well, thanks Rubio :)